# Formatting number to have 2 digits: "Object required"

Tags: vba

Having a look in other threads on the issue, I've found how I can do it, but still i have some issue with my code (printing some values to a file. )

I'm trying to read some data from Excel sheet (it has 32 lines) and print it to a text file in some defined format. The code is for Excel Visual Basic

```
For y = 1 to 32
   Print #1, y.ToString("D2")
   Print #1, "some text" & y.ToString("D2")
Next y
```

I'm getting runtime error 424: object required on both of printing commands.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your error has something to do with the way you opened your text file `#1` or whatever the `y` object is - which we can see neither in the code you provided.

Comment: File was opened with `Open fileName For Output As #1`. There is no other definition for `y`. It is integer

Comment: Is this [tag:vba]? Because you can't attach a method to an integer the way you are doing. What exactly is the purpose of `y`?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, This is Visual Basic for Excel

Comment: `obj.toString` is a [tag:vb.net] method. So what are you using `y` for? Better yet, what is your expected string in it's completed form?

Comment: added some explanation in the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up [Visual Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) with [Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications): they are quite different.

In VBA you can format a number with the `Format` function:

```
 Format(y, "00")
```